# How to obtain 100% branch coverage with gcovr with `if / else if / else`

Tags: c++, gcov, gcovr

I'm using *gcovr* for the first time and have hit a confusing issue with this code:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        bool a = i & 1;
        bool b = i & 2;

        if (a && b)
            printf("a and b\n");
        else if (a && !b)
            printf("a not b\n");
        else
            printf("the other two\n");
    }
```

(The code works as you'd expect, so I'm not going to paste the output.)

However, gcovr decides I don't have full branch coverage:

```
✓✓     5 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
         {
       4     bool a = i & 1;
       4     bool b = i & 2;

✓✓✓✓  4     if (a && b)
       1        printf("a and b\n");
✓✓✓✗  3      else if (a && !b)
       1         printf("a not b\n");
              else
       2         printf("the other two\n");
          }
```

Clearly the one of the four permutations is not handled by the `else if`, but only because it's been handled by the first `if`.

I'm grumpy because the net result is less than 100% branch coverage.  Is this just "the way" or have I fatally misunderstood something?

Comment: If you want 100% branch coverage, you have to have your tests call the function with values that causes it to hit every branch..

Comment: Did this one answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9475970/gcovr-branch-coverage-for-simple-case?rq=1

Comment: @JesperJuhl, but that's just my point: the code _does_ hit every branch.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Klaus but that looks like quite a different scenario

Comment: Note that gcovr takes coverage data directly from GCC's instrumentation, which is on the level of assembly code branches/jumps. But whether the compiler inserts unnecessary branches can also depend on your compiler's optimization level! It's not guaranteed that you can hit all branches that the compiler inserts (especially in C++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to refactor:

```
if (a)
{
    if (b)
    {
        std::cout << "a and b\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "a and not b\n";
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "not a\n";
}
```

In your posted code, the `a` is evaluated in two `if` statements.
The above example removes the `else if` condition.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with `gcovr`. Why would this cause it to recognize all branches are being hit while the other code didn't?

Comment: Just a guess, my example is simpler to evaluate and parse.  This is how I get around static analysis issues and code coverage issues.  I'll let the compiler optimize the code (also, it appears more readable).

Comment: I really don't want to refactor my code*, but I agree this looks like the 'right' solution, so I'll mark accordingly.    [*the example is just a toy version of some much more involved production code]

Comment: @scohe001 Gcovr's branch coverage data describes the assembly-level control flow, but whether the compiler inserts a branch also depends on the compiler's optimization level. Gcovr cannot parse source code. With OP's original code and `-O0` optimizations the compiler would translate `if (a && !b)  {…}` fairly literally as `if (a) { if (!b) { … } } ` – but the control flow prevents `!b` from ever being false when b is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple alternative to wholesale refactoring:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        bool a = i & 1;
        bool b = i & 2;

        if (a && b)
            printf("a and b\n");
        else if (a /*&& !b*/)    // <--- comment out second condition (but leave it in place)
            printf("a not b\n");
        else
            printf("the other two\n");
    }
```

I like this approach because it still encapsulates the logic I want, without redundant (and hence problematic) checks.